# jQuery & HTML: Script works from console yet does not run from file or <script></script>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script for my site where the format and styling changes if the page is viewed from a mobile device. On 2/3 pages on the site the script works great, just as I want. However on the last one, the script for changing the format and styling runs but not completely. I have tried running the code from a script tag at the end and at the beginning of my .html document but nothing changes. the code is:

```
<script>    
    if( jQuery.browser.mobile == true ) {
        alert(true);

        $("#siteHeader").css({
            "position": "absolute",
            "width": $(window).innerWidth + 10 + "px",
        });

        $("#mainContent").css({
            "top": "898px",
        });

        $("#queensTitle").css({
            "display": "none",
        });

        $("#pageTitle").css({
            "text-align": "left",
            "width": "100%",
        });

        $("#pageTitleText").css({
            "width": "93%",
            "margin-left": "20px",
        });

        $("#siteMenu").css({
            "padding-left": "0px",
            "padding-top": "7px",
            "height": "initial",
            "margin-top": "initial",
            "text-align": "center",
            "border-bottom": "28px solid #063e53",
        });

        $(".menuItems").css({
            "width": "100%",
            "height": "initial",
            "float": "initial",
            "margin": "auto",
            "font-size": "5em",
            "font-weight": "700",
            "padding": "0px",
        });

        $("body").width($("#siteMenu").width() - 15).css({
        });

        if ($(location).attr("pathname") == "/drama/about-us-template.html") {
            $("#aboutUsDesc").css({
                "font-size": "1.7em",
            });

            $("#backgroundImageAU").height(247 + $("#aboutUsTitleContainer").height() + $("#aboutUsDescContainer").height() + 21);
        };
    };
</script>
```

The `#siteHeader` format is changed and the `#mainContent` is changed but nothing else changes. However if I run the above code through the console or press CTRL-F5 when running the page it all works as I want it. What could possible be the problem here?

(PS. I have searched stackoverflow and found questions with similar titles but completely different scenarios, i tried their solutions anyways but to no avail)

[Here](http://www.queensu.ca/drama/about-us-template.html) is the link to my site. I am using the Google Chrome Developer Tools Device Emulation and my own phone to test mobile views.

Comment: Why not use CSS media queries for this?

Comment: Hmm, how would i go about selecting only mobile phones? I know one can specify a width for a media query but how about mobile phones?

Answer (score 0):

If at any point the various bits of jQuery does not find an element in the DOM then it will throw an exception and the script will no longer execute.

```
$("#queensTitle")  => undefined
```

then calling

```
$("#queensTitle").css({ ... });
```

will cause the script to stop executing and nothing else after this point will get executed.
You should really could try checking for an element before trying to set the CSS

```
var elem = $("#queensTitle");
if ( elem ) {
   elem.css({ "display": "none" })
}
```

note that you don't need the extra ',' at between the end of the statement and the closing '}' as some browsers will thrown and exception as the parser is expecting additional statements.

Are there any actually any errors or exceptions reported in the browser console when you run the script?

Comment: no i wasn't getting any errors at all. I've edited my scripts so that i am only looking for elements that already exist. Everything is looking good now, thank you!